# Regex - Match only if substring exists

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I'm struggling with a Regex for usage in Fail2Ban.

This is a line of logs I need to crawl:

```
Jul 14 13:30:44 servername kernel: [  803.539059] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=somemacadress SRC=somesourceip DST=somedestinationip LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=18692 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50852 DPT=5003 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

I need the IP *somesourceip* which I am able to get with `SRC=?(?P<host>\S+)`

But: I only want it, if `DPT=5003` is also present. This is the part where I am struggling.

Can somebody help?

Thanks a lot!

I've found `^.*substring.*$` to search for substrings, but I don't manage to combine both.

Comment: Why don't you match it? `\bSRC=(?P<host>\S+).*\sDPT=5003\b` https://regex101.com/r/LPrG03/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
SRC=?(?P<host>\S+).*(?=DPT=5003)
```

This matches your existing one, followed by zero or more other characters, followed by the `DPT=5003` string.

Comment: Side note: did you mean to make the `=` in `SRC=` optional, with the following `?`?